# Is there a way to force a console application to run at a certain window size (using Pdcurses)?

Tags: c++, window, console-application, ncurses, pdcurses

I'm trying my hand at throwing together a minor roguelike in C++, but I've run into a problem - in order to get the game to display correctly, the console window has to be a bit wide (around 45 rows, 115 cols).  It's easy enough to change by right clicking on the menu bar and setting the defaults for windows with the same name, but is there a way I could set it automatically from the code so I don't have to ask potential users to mess with that?  I'm using Pdcurses to handle output, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, this can be set in the shortcut that launches the game, but it's not text and I don't know which libraries or Windows APIs are used to modify it.  That may be simpler than trying to use pdcurses.

However, don't forget Windows does have several console APIs.  Start at [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN for an overview, or skip right to [SetConsoleWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really old question, but I'll post my answer anyway in case it helps someone in the future.
This is what I use in MS Windows:

```
int err = system("mode con lines=45 cols=115");
```

I use this directly before my call to `initscr();`, and it works like a charm.
This is, obviously, not very portable, but it does the trick if all you're developing on is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

What OS? (because it is OS specific)

In Windows [SetConsoleWindowInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686125%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* Resize the terminal to something larger than the physical screen */
    resize_term(2000, 2000);

    /* Get the largest physical screen dimensions */
    getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);

    /* Resize so it fits */
    resize_term(_rows - 1, _cols - 1);

    /* Get the screen dimensions that fit */
    getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);
```