# Method to tell PDCurses to make the window the same size as the physical screen programatically?

Tags: c++, linux, windows-7, curses, pdcurses

Currently I have an c++ console application running on Win7/AIX/Linux.  In the application I use getmaxyx to get the dimensions of the window.

```
getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);
```

On the windows platform i need to play around with the (properties)(layout) options of the running app, to get the screen maximized.  That is a bit of a pain.

Thumbing through  the documention yields nothing of value.

```
lines:  Specifies the number of lines the "screen" will have.
               Directly equates to LINES.
               There is no theoretical maximum.
               The minimum value must be 2.
               Default: 24
cols:   Specifies the number of columns the "screen" will have.
               Directly equates to COLS.
               There is no theoretical maximum.
               The minimum value must be 2.
               Default: 80
```

**Is there any technique that I can use to cause the window to be resized to the physical size of the screen?   Is there a portable way using PDCurses, and curses?   If not, are there any platform specific ways to implement this behavior?**

[Possibly Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214749/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-console-application-to-run-at-a-certain-window-size-u)

[Here perl does it with signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769723/how-to-get-with-curses-the-window-size-from-a-resized-window)

Comment: Those downvoting, I would be delighted to understand why.   This is a real world problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        /* Resize the terminal to something larger than the physical screen */
        resize_term(2000, 2000);

        /* Get the largest physical screen dimensions */
        getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);

        /* Resize so it fits */
        resize_term(_rows - 1, _cols - 1);

        /* Get the screen dimensions that fit */
        getmaxyx(_window, _rows, _cols);
```